# How to add numbers with more than one digit to the word2vec-vocabulary

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to get the embeddings for a list of 1043 nodes with word2vec. When I try to build the vocabulary I find that word2vec takes the list of lists with the nodes and treats them as single digits, eg that "143" becomes "1","4","3".

I already tried to have all the numbers as single entries and see wether it is an formatting problem and went with a buil_vocab_from_freq instead of build_vocab, but this also just produces errors (object of type 'int' has no len()).

My code is the following:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

def generateEmbeddings(all_walks,dimension,min_count):
    model = Word2Vec(min_count = min_count, size = dimension)
    mylist = list(range(1,1043))
    corpus = {}
    j=1
    for i in mylist:
      corpus[str(i)] = j
      j=j+1
    #mylist = [str(i) for i in mylist]
    print(corpus)
    model.build_vocab_from_freq(corpus)
    model.train(mylist, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs = 30)
    #if it reaches this point it throws the error "14 not found in vocabulary"
    print(model.wv.most_similar(positive=['14']))
    return model

print(generateEmbeddings(all_walks,128,2))
```

I want to get the embedding for eg. the number "14" and not "1" as it is by now. Thanks for your help!

//Edit

I managed to fix this, if anybody else is having this specific problem:
you have to format the list as mentioned as [["1","102","43"],["54","43"]] etc.
You cant change the old list at runtime (or at least it didnt work the way I did it), so you could create a new list at runtime with

```
new_list = []
    for i in all_walks:
      temp_list = []
      for j in i:
        temp_list.append(str(j))
      new_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: How is `all_walks` prepared, and what is its type/contents? `Word2Vec` expects as its training-corpus an iterable sequence of texts, where each text is a list-of-string-tokens. Nothing in your current code fragment appears to access (or create) such a training-corpus. (A list of integers – `list(range(1, 1043))` – is not a sequence where each item is a list-of-tokens.)

Comment: all_walks is a list like [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[10,11,12],[10,14,15,900]] with a few-hundred entries.

Comment: It would need to be a list-of-lists-of-strings to be what `Word2Vec` typically expects. For example: `[['1','2','3'],['1','2','4'],['10','11','12'],['10','14','15','900']]`

Comment: Okay, this actually did it. I tried this before, but only now managed to get it right by creating a new list with two for-loops instead of changing all_walks at runtime. Now its up and running, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion above, the working approach will feed `Word2Vec` the kind of corpus it expects – an iterable sequence, where each item is a list of string-tokens.

So, a list-of-lists-of-strings would work, something like...

```
[
  ['1','2','3'],
  ['1','2','4'],
  ['10','11','12'],
  ['10','14','15','900']
]
```

...rather than anything with raw ints in it (like `list(range(1, 1043)`).